# Anylogic: Adding text label to Rectangular Wall

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to add a text label on top of rectangular walls in Anylogic? I am trying to dynamically create rectangular walls using code and then adding labels. So far I am able to create the walls but the text label does not appear on top of the walls as I want it.

Comment: I assume you want to create dynamic text objects to label the walls? Since you are creating them dynamically you need to create the labels dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating walls dynamically I assume you also want to create your text dynamically.

There is a little trick in AnyLogic where you can view the code that gets created for you by AnyLogic discussed in [this](https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/how-to-programmatically-redraw-a-chart) blog post

You can use the code snipped below to draw a Text object and add it to the presentation collection (which is needed for it to be displayed)

```
Font _text_Font = new Font("SansSerif", 0, 10 ); // Only needed if you don't have any text in your agent else _text_Font gets created for you.

ShapeText myProgramticallyCreatedText = new ShapeText(
        SHAPE_DRAW_2D, true,170.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
        black,"Programatically Created text",
        _text_Font, ALIGNMENT_LEFT );
        
presentation.add(myProgramticallyCreatedText);
```

Here is the syntax for creating your

```
ShapeText(boolean ispublic, double x, double y, double rotation, java.awt.Color color, java.lang.String text, java.awt.Font font, TextAlignment alignment)
```

Constructs a 2D-only text shape with specific attributes.

```
ShapeText(ShapeDrawMode drawMode, boolean ispublic, double x, double y, double z, double rotation, java.awt.Color color, java.lang.String text, java.awt.Font font, TextAlignment alignment)
```

Constructs a text shape with specific attributes.

Depending on whether or not you have 3D or not you can rotate the text by changing the correct parameters

If you want to make it visible in 3d and also rotate it correctly you need to create a group, add the text to that group, then create a new group, and the group this new group and then rotate the first group. Like below

```
Font _text_Font = new Font("SansSerif", 0, 10 );

ShapeText myProgramticallyCreatedText = new ShapeText(
        SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true,170.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
        black,"Programatically Created text",
        _text_Font, ALIGNMENT_LEFT );
        
ShapeGroup innerGroup = new ShapeGroup(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 170.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0 , myProgramticallyCreatedText );
ShapeGroup outerGroup = new ShapeGroup(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 170.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0 , innerGroup );
innerGroup.setRotationX(-PI/2 );
presentation.add(outerGroup);
```

(P.S. I figured all of this out using the trick from the blog post referenced above ;-) )

Comment: This will not, however, turn your text "vertical" (like a clock hanging from a wall). You need to add it to a group and rotate that, see my tip below.

Comment: Yes of course. OP did not specify that the text needed to be vertical though ;-)

Comment: I added the code for this as it is likely that askers of this question will also require it. Thank you for the prod @Benjamin

Comment: Just a related question on this: Can agents pass through shape objects? I am trying to create different stations around a store and I use rectangular walls to block off the area. I wonder if that is needed or if just using a shape object eg rectangle is enough?

Comment: @user1234 Was my answer sufficient to your question? If so, please accept it and upvote it if you think worthy ;-) On your question agents can pass through anything, if you are referring to pedestrians they are only constrained by the Wall and some other Space Markup elements found in the pedestrain library

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

If it should show horizontally on top of the wall, just ensure it has the same x,y coordinates as the center of the wall and then set the z-coordinate higher than the wall height.

If you want to show it vertically (like a clock hanging from the wall), you need to set the xY coordinates carefully so it does not display inside the wall. Z coordinate half way of the wall height. And then you need to do a trick to turn the text: put it into a group and rotate the group. The example model "Airport terminal" does that, check it out